# Open hashing vs closed hashing

Tags: hash-tables, hashing

What are advantages of closed hashing over open hashing?
I know the difference between those two but can't figure out why would closed hashing be better in any way.
Thanks.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hash_table#Collision_resolution